# How to get a module instance in PRISM

Tags: module, prism, instance

I have a PRISM desktop app which loads modules from a directory with the help of the DirectoryModuleCatalog.

Everything is fine, except that I cannot find a way to get the instance of a loaded module.
IModuleManager and IModuleCatalog don't have a method like *getInstance(ModuleInfo)* or similar.

See

```
moduleManager.LoadModule(moduleInfo.ModuleName);
```

This line loads the module properly(moduleManager is of type IModuleManager), but what do I have to do next to get the actual instance of this module?

The modules are loaded on demand of the user, so I cannot register all modules at startup within the bootstrapper.

Comment: Why do you need a module instance? Please describe your problem, not it's solution you think of.

Comment: @PVitt The loaded modules implement a specific interface and I need to call a start() method on all of those loaded module instances.

Comment: Why do you have to call start on all modules?

Comment: Because the user can select multiple modules, all of which can be startet and stopped in operation. If the user wants to stop say 3 modules at once, I have to call stop() on those modules, so that they change their state. Is there really no way to get at least the type of the loaded modules? I cannot even register the modules with the unity container?!

Comment: I think you should ask a question "How to load and unload prism modules during runtime".

Comment: I know how to load them, everything is fine on this part. I don't need to unload modules, I just want to change the state of some of the loaded modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by Module instance you mean the class that implement IModule, then you must explicitly register the instance into the container to be able to get it.

Although the aforementioned will work, you should not take that approach at all. The idea is that the module classes are specific to a particular module and should only be used for module initialization purposes.

I would place each module's Start method in a separate component (IStartable), register each component in the container with a different Id and resolve/import an IEnumerable to get all instances that have the start method.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe This could be made by using IEventAggregator, several modules can  subscribe to an event that is published by other, for example Save, Undo, Redo, etc. any module should perform the specific module action base on your own state.
https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html