# Iterate through PRISM modules and execute respective "finalize" methods

Tags: c#, prism

My app consists of a Shell and many modules which are loaded from a directory. I'd like to add a Finalize() method to each of these modules so they can perform their own required cleanup/shutdown code such as closing files, freeing sockets, perform saves/backups, etc.

I know this concept can be easily achieved with event aggregation and publishing an event on shutdown, but I'd much rather iterate through each module and call this Finalize() method which returns a status int showing whether or not the module encountered any problems during finalization.

So far I've created the following simple interface, and had the appropriate modules implement it.

```
public interface IFinalizeModule
{
    int Finalize();
}
```

Is it possible to iterate through the modules in the module catalog and do something like this without creating additional instances of them? The closest thing I've found is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887028/how-to-get-a-module-instance-in-prism) but I can't wrap my head around his explanation

> I would place each module's Start method in a separate component (IStartable), register each component in the container with a different Id and resolve/import an IEnumerable to get all instances that have the start method.

This code doesn't work, but it's what I'm trying to achieve

```
        foreach (IModule module in ModuleCatalog)
        {
            int exitcode = module.Finalize();

            if (exitcode != 0)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are short lived. They are created, initialized and garbage collected. The only job of a module is to perform registrations.

If you have services that need to be shut down when the application is shut down, you have to notify those services if you're about to shut down. Either through an event they subscribe to or by creating a `RegistryOfServicesThatNeedToBeShutDown`.

Example expanding on my comment (if you insist on cleaning up on module-level):

```
class MyModule : IModule
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<IMyService, DisposeMe>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
        _container.RegisterType<IMyOtherService, DisposeMeToo>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );

        _container.RegisterType<IModuleCleanUp, CleanUpMyModule>( nameof( MyModule ) );
    }

    private class CleanUpMyModule : IModuleCleanUp
    {
        void Finalize()
        {
            _container.Resolve<IMyService>().Dispose();            
            _container.Resolve<IMyOtherService>().Dispose();            
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a regular module and its clean-up-code next to each other. But the code looks ugly a bit, and there are things to be aware of:

- if someone resolves `IMyService` after the clean-up, you're done for
- you don't even know whether the type registered as `IMyService` requires clean-up: another module that's initialized after `MyModule` might register a different type for `IMyService`

Comment: Is it reasonable to somehow keep these modules from being GC'd? Having the cleanup code in a method in the Module makes it very readable and also you have all the objects created during initialization easily available. Also, with this method I'd be able to "finalize" each module 1 at a time instead of a broadcasted event, and get their return value on their shutdown status.

Comment: `all the objects created during initialization` - I would avoid that if at all possible. Just register your types and let the container decide when to create objects. Regarding keeping modules around - you _can_ do that, of course, but the modules aren't made for this. It will be surprising for any developer looking at the code in a few months for sure. And the modules provide nothing to help you here, so you gain nothing from using the modules for this.